# CrossRegionError #Office365 #AzureDataFactory

Tags: office365, azure-data-factory

I am trying to download attachment from Outlook mails(office 365). Perform a Copydata Activity in Azure data factory. After showing extract massage,pipelie is failed due to "***CrossRegionFailure***".
All my azure and office 365 portals in same region. Can any one help me on this please.

Error Message:***Office365 data loading failed to execute. office365LoadErrorType: PermanentError. The extraction failed because the region in which the user data resides is different from the region this pipeline is running. Please deploy this pipeline in the correct region for the given tenant***

[image: 1]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

> The extraction failed because the region in which the user data resides is different from the region this pipeline is running. Please deploy this pipeline in the correct region for the given tenant.

the above error can cause due to your data factory is in different region than Microsoft 365 (Office 365) tenant.

From [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365?tabs=data-factory),

> The Azure subscription hosting the data factory, Synapse workspace, and sink data storage must belong to the same Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant as the Microsoft 365 (Office 365) tenant.

**For both Storage account and Data factory, select an Azure region that is in the same area as your Microsoft 365 region.**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [Load data from Microsoft 365 (Office 365)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/data-connect-quickstart?tabs=Microsoft365)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pratiklad. But, i am using only one tenant. Also my data factory and blobs are in same region which is Central US.